# get user_id Devise in nested form rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, userid

I'm follow this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 for nested form.

I have 3 model the first **user.rb**:

```
class User
 has_many :boards, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts

end
```

The second model its  **board.rb**

```
class Board
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy , :autosave => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
belongs_to :user
end
```

The third model its **post.rb**

```
class Post
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :board
end
```

I want create a **new post** since a board form and I have in **boards_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @board = Board.new
  @board.posts.build
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @board }
 end
end

def create
 @board = current_user.boards.new(params[:board])
 @board.user = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @board.save
    format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

With this 2 methods I get **every attributes of posts** in my views. in my console if I put after create a board **Post.first** I get:

```
1.9.2-p290 :007 > Post.first
=> #<Post _id: 4f0b0b211d41c80d08002afe, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-01-09 15:43:29 UTC, user_id: nil, board_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f0b0b1b1d41c80d08002afd'), content: "hello post 2">
```

But If you take a look I get **user_id: nil**.

In normal model I get user id for example in create action of controller I put **@post.user = current_user.id or @post.user = current_user**

**How Can I get the user_id in nested model post through from nested forms?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create
 @board = current_user.boards.new(params[:board])
 #@board.user = current_user - you don't need this line, since you create new board record using current_user object
 # assign current_user id to the each post.user_id
@board.posts.each {|post| post.user_id = current_user}

respond_to do |format|
   if @board.save
     format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
   else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for dont working for me: I'm using mongoid. I get the next error: `BSON::InvalidDocument (Cannot serialize an object of class User into BSON.):` The post is created but the user_id is still nil, `MONGODB myapp_development['boards'].insert([{"name"=>"board 2", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f0b6bc51d41c80d08002bcf'), "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f0b19691d41c80d08002b20'), "slug"=>"board-2", "created_at"=>2012-01-09 22:35:54 UTC}])
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5158ms`

Comment: The problem its fixed :D. I have fixed the problem with this bucle for: `for post in @board.posts
    post.user_id = current_user.id
    end` Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply set the `user_id` property.

In your code you are assigning the `current_user` object to the association.

This should work:

```
def create
 @board = current_user.boards.new(params[:board])
 @board.user_id = current_user.id
respond_to do |format|
  if @board.save
    format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: thank you, but the user_id **for Post its nil for me** :(. The user_id for board working fine, but user_id for Post its nil. I don't know how get the user_id for Post. I need access to attributes of User since Post with Post.user.name or Post.user.email for example. If I put Post.first I get again: `<Post _id: 4f0b202e1d41c80d08002b62, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-01-09 17:13:18 UTC, user_id: nil, board_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f0b20291d41c80d08002b61'), content: "Dont working">`

Comment: I have tried this: @board.posts.build(:user_id => current_user.id) but don't working for me.